# Lookup object for string enum "has no index signature"

Tags: typescript

I've got a string enum whose values should each be associated with a display name, like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
  key1 = 'one',
  key2 = 'two',
  key3 = 'three',
}

const myKey: MyEnum = 'two' as MyEnum; // This value is only known at runtime

const lookupResult = {
  [MyEnum.key1]: 'display name for key1',
  [MyEnum.key2]: 'display name for key2',
}[myKey];
```

But my use of the lookup object produces this error:

> TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{
>   [MyEnum.key1]: string; [MyEnum.key2]: string; }' has no index
>   signature.

How can I match `myKey` to its display name without the error?

Should I maybe not be using an enum at all?  I need both the enum values and the display names, in various contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Just use enum key.

```
enum MyEnum {
  key1 = 'one',
  key2 = 'two',
  key3 = 'three',
}

const lookupResult = {
  [MyEnum.key1]: 'display name for key1',
  [MyEnum.key2]: 'display name for key2',
}[MyEnum.key2];
```

Comment: The value of `myKey` is only known at runtime - I'll edit my question to make that more clear

Comment: Why you can't use just const myKey = 'value from runtime' ?

Comment: BTW: I have not any errors while executing code from your example. Typescript version 2.8.0